# Why am I getting bad_alloc error while implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, vector, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to pre compute all the prime no. on a big range from 1 to 1000000005 using Sieve of Eratosthenes but getting an error after compiling my code ... I think the problem is related to vector's size but when when I printed out using P.max_size() I got no. bigger than my limit so, I think the max limit is still not reached but still I am stuck at that error .
Please help me

I am saving all primes as 1 and rest as 0 in the vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long long i,j;
  vector<int>P;
  P.reserve(1000000005);
  for(i=0;i<=1000000;i++)
  {
    P.push_back(1);
  }
 P[0]=0;
 P[1]=0;

for(i=2;i<=sqrt(1000000);i++)
{
  if(P[i]==1)
  {
     for(j=2;i*j<=100000;j++)
       P[i*j]=0;
  }
}

long long T,N,M;
scanf("%lld",&T);

while(T--)
{
 scanf("%lld %lld",&N,&M);
   for(i=N;i<=M;i++)
    {
      if(P[i]==1)
      printf("%lld\n",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: simple, memory request can not be fulfilled. You are trying to reserve amount of memory that is not available

Comment: In a 32-bit computer, this  `P.reserve(1000000005);` will take up `4 * 1000000005` bytes. Which is close to 4GB. Go 64-bit and it won't be a problem, but for a 32-bit machine, you can't allocate this much memory...

Comment: Note also that `P.max_size()` will tell you the numerical limit for the `size` variable, that's the limit where "if you add one more element, size will be zero" - on a 64-bit machine, that will be the full 64 bits, but even if you buy every stick of memory ever produced in the world, you won't be able to allocate that much memory, as current generation 64-bit processors are limited to 48 bits of RAM, so 1024TB.

Comment: Use a `std::deque` instead ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`P.max_size()` indicates *how large the vector can be*, which is quite different from how much memory is available/can be allocated at a particular moment. `bad_alloc`exception  is thrown when `new` operator can not fulfill the allocation request for a given size of memory. As @Mats pointed out, clearly in your platform the allocation fails.